# Compare in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Description:
I want to use a syntax like COMP I:\folder1 Z:\folder2 to compare all files in my I drive with the content of my z drive. I only need to compare their names to see if one exsists in the other. I need to recurse into the subdirectories because there are many located in both drives, I understand I need to use a batch script using a FOR loop and the PUSHD and POPD command.

QUESTION:
How do I do this?

Comment: Today, i have written this same sentence, but anyway... Is there any reason not to use robocopy? You can instruct it to do all the work without having to copy any file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output from FOR /?

```
FOR /R [[drive:]path] %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

    Walks the directory tree rooted at [drive:]path, executing the FOR
    statement in each directory of the tree.  If no directory
    specification is specified after /R then the current directory is
    assumed.  If set is just a single period (.) character then it
    will just enumerate the directory tree.
```

So you'd do something like

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion ENABLEEXTENSIONS

for /R P:\ %%F in (*.*) DO (
set fileFull=%%~fF
set filePath=%%~pF
set fileDrive=%%~dF
set fileName=%%~nF
set fileExtension=%%~xF
call :checker "!filePath!" "!fileName!" "!fileExtension!"
) 
goto :eof

:checker
set fileTarget="c:%~1%~2%~3"
if not exist %fileTarget% echo %fileTarget% not found
goto :eof
```

In this case, the script is getting all the filenames in P:\ and its subdirectories and telling me if the file doesn't exist on the same path in C:

Answer (score 0):

List folder differences over a tree:

This uses robocopy to create the list - **don't remove** `/L` as this switch makes robocopy only list the information.

```
robocopy "d:\source\folder one" "c:\target\folder two" /L /fp /njs /njh /ndl /ns /np /mir
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to avoid third party utilities:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET FOLDER1=I:\Folder1\
SET FOLDER2=Z:\Folder2\
ECHO SET FNAME=%%1 ^& @ECHO %%FNAME:%FOLDER1%=%%^>^>FILES1.TXT>FILES1.BAT
ECHO SET FNAME=%%1 ^& @ECHO %%FNAME:%FOLDER2%=%%^>^>FILES2.TXT>FILES2.BAT
IF EXIST FILES1.TXT DEL FILES1.TXT
IF EXIST FILES2.TXT DEL FILES2.TXT   
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%* IN ('DIR /S /B /ON "%FOLDER1%"') DO CALL FILES1.BAT "%%*"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%* IN ('DIR /S /B /ON "%FOLDER2%"') DO CALL FILES2.BAT "%%*"
ECHO Files from "%FOLDER1%" which are not found in "%FOLDER2%"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%* IN (FILES1.TXT) DO (FIND %%* FILES2.TXT >NUL || ECHO %%*)
ECHO Files from "%FOLDER2%" which are not found in "%FOLDER1%"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%* IN (FILES2.TXT) DO (FIND %%* FILES1.TXT >NUL || ECHO %%*)
```